# Something is wrong in my oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, select, triggers

I need help in one of my Oracle Trigger syntax

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TRG_TRIGGER" AFTER INSERT
ON T_TABLE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO T_TABLE_TEST
  (DOC_ID , DOC_NAME)
VALUES
(:NEW.DOC_ID, SELECT DOC_NAME FROM OTHER_TABLE WHERE DOC_ID=DOC_ID);
```

Need DOC_NAME from other table. I think only my select query needs to be modified?

Comment: "something is wrong" isn't very helpful; if you get errors you should include those in the question. If it just says it compiled with errors, use `show errors` or query `user_errors` to get the details; if it compiles OK but get an error when you insert then show the insert statement and the error. It's helpful to include the table definitions too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have suggested, you could rewrite the insert...values statement to be an insert...as select statement, and that would make the most sense.

Just fyi, there are two problems with your original insert statement that leap out at me:

1. You specified `doc_id = doc_id` in your select statement, whereas I think you meant `doc_id = :new.doc_id`. Your query would return all rows from the other table, and you'd get `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`, if your query was able to run.
2. You didn't enclose the select statement within brackets. It should be:

--

```
INSERT INTO T_TABLE_TEST
 (DOC_ID , DOC_NAME)
VALUES 
 (:NEW.DOC_ID, (SELECT DOC_NAME FROM OTHER_TABLE WHERE DOC_ID=:NEW.DOC_ID));
```

Comment: Hmm, you've marked this one as correct, which - whilst I suppose it does technically answer your original question - I didn't expect. Sagi's or Wernfried's answers are better, imho - the insert-as-select looks a lot less clunky in this instance than the insert-values query does!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify which doc_name to select, so I think you are missing a where clause.. try this:

```
INSERT INTO T_TABLE_TEST
(DOC_ID , DOC_NAME)
SELECT t.doc_id, t.DOC_NAME FROM OTHER_TABLE t where t.doc_id = :NEW.DOC_ID;
```

Of course I guessed that other table have column named doc_id, change it to the relation column.

Answer (score 2):

The insert must be like this:

```
INSERT INTO T_TABLE_TEST
  (DOC_ID , DOC_NAME)
SELECT :NEW.DOC_ID, DOC_NAME FROM OTHER_TABLE where doc_id = :NEW.DOC_ID;
```

Just a note, you can skip `REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD` since `OLD` and `NEW` are defaults.

Comment: I don't think this is what he want, look at my solution

Comment: @sagi I still see errors with your solution..what could be wrong

Comment: @AlexPoole, yes, I missed that. I was focusing on the syntax error.